# Is there any way to solve error HTTP ERROR 503?

Tags: html, eclipse, jsp, jetty, http-error

I am getting HTTP ERROR 503. Even after restarting the server, the error persists. I am using Eclipse IDE.

Following is the screenshot of the error:-

[image]

I've been using **clean jetty:run** command and things were working perfectly but I don't understand why I'm getting this error now.

Following is the error log:-

```
    [WARNING] Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@299b9851{/,file:///Users/user_name/eclipse-workspace/project_name/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{file:///Users/shashankk/eclipse-workspace/project_name/src/main/webapp/}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple servlets map to path /MessageServlet: controller.UserPromptServlet[mapped:ANNOTATION:controller.UserPromptServlet],controller.MessageServlet[mapped:ANNOTATION:controller.MessageServlet]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.updateMappings(ServletHandler.java:1433)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doStart(ServletHandler.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.doStart(SecurityHandler.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler.doStart(ConstraintSecurityHandler.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doStart(SessionHandler.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] Started ServerConnector@5fbae1ca{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[INFO] Started @17004ms
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key line ...

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple servlets map to path /MessageServlet: controller.UserPromptServlet[mapped:ANNOTATION:controller.UserPromptServlet],controller.MessageServlet[mapped:ANNOTATION:controller.MessageServlet]

You have 2 classes that have an annotation declaring the same `url-pattern` of `/MessageServlet`.

1. `controller.UserPromptServlet`
2. `controller.MessageServlet`

Fix your annotations, rebuild, and you should be ok.